# regex_replace issue

Tags: c++, regex, string, c++11, visual-studio-2012

I'm using **C++11** (windows 7 64 bit , visual studio 2012)

I'm using a loop to replace some substring by another one. 
I have a file that has numbers separated by a double slash (//). 
for example:

```
10//20//1 3//4//5 5//2//1 to 10 20 1 3 4 5 5 2 1
```

However, when I attempt to do it with **regex**, it seems that I'm doing something wrong. Nothing happens. Also, where could I read more about **regex C++11**

```
string fData(data.substr(2));
string replaceStr("10//20//1 3//4//5 5//2//1");
regex r("//"
regex_replace(fData,r," ");
```

but nothing happens.

Like I said before, if you can also point out **a web page that I can read more about this**, besides the answer. I have it working, but I wanted to start using regex.

***Thanks***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`regex_replace` does not do an in-place edit of the string; it **returns** the output string.

For example:
`auto out = regex_replace(fData,r," ");`

In this example, out will be a string of the expected value ("10 20 1 3 4 5 5 2 1"). [This cheat sheet](http://cpprocks.com/wp-content/uploads/c++11-regex-cheatsheet.pdf) is quite useful (from http://cpprocks.com/regex-cheatsheet/). Enjoy!

Comment: In terms of performance. using regex_replace is it the same as looping and replacing with find and replace?

Comment: `regex_replace` seems like it uses a regex iterator underneath the hood (don't take my word on it). From what I have seen from other answers and the internet, the C++11 `regex_replace` is fairly slow compared to other languages' implementation of regular expressions (Python, for example). You can benchmark it yourself to see which version would suit your performance needs.